# How can I populate a combo box with JSON array elements from URL?

Tags: c#, json

I want to grab all of the elements from [THIS](https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/api/versions.json) JSON array and populate comboBox1 with them. This is a picture of what the combo box would look like when populated

[image]

How could I go about doing that?

I'm not asking for anyone to write the code and simply hand it over. I want to know how all the code works in detail if possible. I'm very unskilled with C# and a complete beginner to JSON.

Comment: Did you check any library to handle JSON data from C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try getting the values using the `Microsoft.Net.Http.HttpClient`. Deserialize the response using Json.NET (`Newtonsoft.Json`) to an enumeration of strings (`IEnumerable<string>`).

Then set the DataSource property of your combobox to the value of this enumeration (`myCombobox.DataSource = myEnumeration;`). That should do the trick.

As requested, the code for reference:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/api/versions.json");
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            comboBox1.DataSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I would greatly appreciate the code for reference and I appreciate the explanation.